# Index out of range exception in SqlDataReader

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net, indexoutofrangeexception

Whenever I try to use "View in browser" option in my ASP.NET MVC project, I get the error "index out of range" in `SqlDataReader`.

Here is the code for my `SqlDataReader`:

```
public List<User> View(ActivityMode a)
{
        SqlConnection con = ConnectionDAL.SQL();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "Sp_UserReg";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Activity", a.ToString());

        List<User> lst = null;

        con.Open();

        using (con)
        {
            SqlDataReader DR =cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (DR.HasRows)
            {
                lst = new List<User>();

                while (DR.Read())
                {
                    User obj = new User();
                    obj.Id = Convert.ToInt32(DR["@Id"]);
                    obj.DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(DR["@DOB"]);
                    obj.EmailAddress = DR["@EmailAddress"].ToString();
                    obj.FirstName = DR["@FirstName"].ToString();
                    obj.LastName = DR["@LastName"].ToString();
                    obj.Password = DR["@Password"].ToString();
                    obj.SecurityAnswer = DR["SecurityAnswer"].ToString();
                    obj.SecurityQuestion = DR["@SecurityAnswer"].ToString();

                    lst.Add(obj);
                }

                lst.TrimExcess();
            }

            return lst;
        }
    }       
}
```

The code enters the while statement and when it reaches at Id column it throws the error. I also tried to comment Id but it then gives me error on next column.

Here is the query in the database:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[Sp_UserReg]
    (@Id int = null,
     @FullName varchar(100) = null,
     @Password varchar(50) = null,
     @EmailAddress varchar(50) = null,
     @DOB datetime = null,
     @SecurityQuestion varchar(100) = null,
     @SecurityAnswer varchar(100) = null,
     @Activity varchar(50) = null)
AS BEGIN
    IF(@Activity = 'Add')
        INSERT INTO UserReg (FullName,[Password], EmailAddress, SecurityQuestion, SecurityAnswer, DOB)
        VALUES (@FullName, @Password, @EmailAddress, @SecurityQuestion, @SecurityAnswer, @DOB)

    IF(@Activity = 'Delete')
        DELETE FROM UserReg 
        WHERE id = @id

    IF(@Activity = 'View')
        SELECT * 
        FROM [UserReg]

    IF(@Activity = 'Update')
        UPDATE UserReg 
        SET FullName = @fullName,
            [Password] = @Password,
            EmailAddress = @EmailAddress

    IF(@Activity = 'ViewById')
        SELECT * 
        FROM UserReg 
        WHERE Id = @Id
End
```

Comment: I think you should drop the @ sign when referring to the fields with the data reader.

Comment: What am I? an idiot I guess :p Thanks Its working now :)

Comment: Np. I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should drop the @ sign when referring to the fields with the data reader.